# CSS Select all text with a certain font

Tags: css

Is there way to select all elements with a certain font?
I tried:

```
[font-family*=Menlo]{
    font-family: OpenDyslexicMono;
}
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need javascript

Answer (score -1):

If the target web page:

1. Locate a text with the font you want to target.
2. Inspect an element with the font you want target.
3. Once the developer tools opens, open the "Computed" tab in the right side panel.
4. In the filter box search for `font-family`.
5. See the CSS selector applying the font and use the same selector to apply the new font.

Answer (score -1):

I think this global selector will help to do that

```
  * { /* this solution best and along the side worst also help you select all the elements */
       font-family: OpenDyslexicMono;
    }

    html, body { /* this allows the children to inherit this style */
       font-family: OpenDyslexicMono;
    }
    
    body * { /* assigns this style to every tag inside of your body tag */
        font-family: OpenDyslexicMono;
    }
    
    p, span, a, etc { /* you decided what tags would most likely contain text to apply that style */
        font-family: OpenDyslexicMono;
    }
```

Comment: The goal is not setting the font to something. The goal is selecting elements with a font.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* Select all text with a font size of 16 pixels */
*[style*="font-size: 16px;"] {
/* Your styling rules here */
}
```